# Главное чтоб вас 10шт не набралось :)

Tags: грамматика

I am trying to figure out this ironic sentence, without context, what 10'шт' would refer to? An inanimate object or a person?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

шт - сокращение от штук.

Обычно штуками считают неодушевлённые предметы, но в шутку так могут сказать и о людях.

Так что фраза: "главное, чтобы вас 10 штук (то есть 10 человек) не набралось". Смысл, скорее всего, тот, что "вас" не должно быть слишком много.

Answer (score -1):

шт - Used to indicate the count of objects than person